# Why is the left-hand sum of negative binomial probabilities is equal to the right hand sum of ordinary binomial probabilities?

Tags: probability, distributions, negative-binomial-distribution

The textbook I am using states that the left-hand sum of negative binomial probabilities is equal to the right hand sum of ordinary binomial probabilities.Why is this so? The book uses the following example:

For the sake of argument let us consider the die example where 1 or 2 was called a success. Suppose we set as a goal the obtaining of 4 successes but agree to roll no more than 10 times. Our goal can be achieved in two ways. First , if the fourth success is obtained on either the fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight, ninth or tenth roll, the goal is accomplished.

The second way to achieve the goal in 10 tries is to plan to roll exactly 10 times and count 4,5,6,7,8,9 or 10 successes. In both cases we are considering the event "the goal is achieved in 10 trials" so that the two probabilities must be the same.(Why? aren't the two cases different?)

In other words why is the probability of getting exactly r successes in at most n trials equal to the probability of getting r or more successes in exactly n trials? or at least this is my interpretation of the given example.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you come up with any situation with $n$ trials where the two events (exactly $r$ successes in at most $n$ and at least $r$ in $n$) are different? For what values of $n$ and $r$ can that occur?

Comment: i think both scenarios are different, in the former r stays the same but n goes from r to n but in the latter n stays the same but r goes from r to n, so they will be different for all values of n and r. But I am definitely wrong and I cant understand why?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example where the events are different?  That may help us pin down the nature of your question.  Here's what I mean by "concrete example:" suppose $n=2$ and $r=1.$ Write the individual outcomes in order as "S" for success and "F" for non-success. The possible experimental outcomes are SS, SF, FS, and FF.  The event "at least 1 success in 2 trials" is {SS, SF, FS}. The event "1 success in at most 2 trials" is also {SS, SF, FS}. Obviously SF and FS belong there, but SS is there too because there was exactly one success in the first trial. What's your counterexample?

Comment: but n is not fixed in the negative binomial distribution so the event "1 success in at most 2 trials" is {S,FS} and the event "at least 1 success in 2 trials" is {SS, SF, FS} and the probabilities of both sets is similar(you can check it yourself) this is what confuses me.The book justifies it by saying that the end goal of getting 1 success is achieved so that the probabilities must be the same. Also thanks for keeping up

Comment: Your notation "S" (success on the first trial) refers to the set {SS, SF} (also success on the first trial).

Comment: but in the negative binomial distribution we stop the experiment when a certain number of successes(in this case one) have been achieved so "S" is just "S", it is equivalent to saying that we got one success in one attempt, but on the other hand  {SS,SF} is equivalent to saying that we attempted two trials and got success in the first one. The probability in both cases is same but to me they both seem different things. Also the probability of "S" is also equal to the probability of {SSS,SSF,SFF,SFS} and apparently this will be the case for any number of n.

Comment: Therein lies your misconception.  You may imagine the second trial was attempted after you saw the first S, but its result was not reported to you.  That shouldn't change any probabilities you assess.

Comment: Okay thanks extremely grateful for your time I think I am getting there. Anyway thanks again. Do you think that understanding this kind of stuff will get easier with time or is this ability a constant?

Comment: By thinking long and carefully about such issues, one learns over time.  This issue, btw, is at the heart of a famous exchange of letters between Blaise Pascal and Pierre de Fermat in 1654 concerning the ["Problem of the Points."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points#Pascal_and_Fermat)

Comment: Thanks for the link so are you saying that I was not stuck at some trivial stuff :)